# Applying for EU family permit / residence card as the adult child of an EU citizen

Tags: immigration

I'm member of an EU family. I have an EU residence card issued by Italy and have traveled previously to the UK with my father as a European citizen. I want to stay and remain in the United Kingdom. I would like to obtain a family permit from the UK.

Questions:

- When can I make an application? I have been present in the county 1 month.
- What documents will need to for supporting my application?
- Can my father travel and leave me alone for one month?
- Does such a thing exist and is it difficult to obtain?
- My Italian father can not work because health reasons.

I found a contract of work for 1 year. Will that help the application?

Comment: Beyond the current question on Travel, I think you have asked this or a very similar question before, perhaps using a different account. Did you delete it? Did it get any answers or comments? Are you under 21 or a dependent of your father?

Comment: 21 old , I'm in charge of my father

Comment: @WalidHadjali to be a "dependent" of your father, your father must be paying a significant portion (I guess more than half, but I am not certain) of your living expenses. If you're working and he's not, that seems unlikely. In any event, you won't be able to reside in the UK unless your father also resides there. Is that the plan?

Comment: Also, you can [merge](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts ([Walid Hadj ali](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/19570/walid-hadj-ali) and [Walid Hadj ali](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/19587/walid-hadj-ali)).  If you log in with the account that owns the question, you can comment on the question and on the answers to the question.  You will also be able to edit the question should you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you must apply for leave to enter based on your own situation.

That situation would be that you wish to work in the United Kingdom for 1 year while your Italian father will retain his residence in Italy.

So you should apply for the corresponding UK visa in Italy based **soly** on your citizenship. You should also state **clearly** that your Italian father will remain in Italy.

Any attempt to 'play around' with the rules (such as you father arriving with you and then leaving) will bring you no joy.